# Reading EMNIST dataset

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am building a CNN using tensorflow in python, but having problem with loading the data from EMNIST dataset. Can anyone please show me a sample code of retrieving each image in a batch and pass during the training session?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code design and writing service. Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of formats of the EMNIST dataset...the one I've found easiest to understand is the CSV version on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/crawford/emnist, where each row is a separate image, there are 785 columns where the first column = class_label and each column after represents one pixel value (784 total for a 28 x 28 image).

You can check out one of my implementations of an EMNIST CNN using Keras, where your dataset loading can be similar:

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = pd.read_csv("data/emnist-balanced-train.csv")

train, validate = train_test_split(raw_data, test_size=0.1) # change this split however you want

x_train = train.values[:,1:]
y_train = train.values[:,0]

x_validate = validate.values[:,1:]
y_validate = validate.values[:,0]
```

from https://github.com/Josh-Payne/cs230/blob/master/Alphanumeric-Augmented-CNN/augmented-cnn.py